# How to track changes in records in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have the following table which has tracking records of all students.

```
|==========================================|
| ID      |  Department     | Date         |
|==========================================|
| 001     | English         | Feb 3 2017   |
| 001     | English         | Feb 4 2017   |
| 001     | Science         | Mar 1 2017   |
| 001     | Science         | Apr 2 2017   |
| 001     | Maths           | Apr 7 2017   |
| 002     | Maths           | Feb 1 2017   |
| 002     | Maths           | Apr 7 2017   |
| 003     | Maths           | Apr 3 2017   |
| 004     | Science         | Feb 1 2017   |
| 004     | Maths           | Apr 7 2017   |
|==========================================|
```

I need to fetch the previous record just before when the student has changed the department. For the example above, the record set returned should be

**For 001,**

```
| 001     | English         | Feb 4 2017   |
| 001     | Science         | Apr 2 2017   |
```

**For 002 and 003**

No changes

**For 004**

```
| 004     | Science         | Feb 1 2017   |
```

There is also a possibility that the same user can change back to the same department. for example, user001 can change from dept a to dept b to dept c and back to dept a. I have read about T-SQL send and receive. But not sure if that would help in this scenario. Please help.

Comment: What is the version of SQL Server?

Comment: I don't understand; you want to query the table to find those records, or you want to get these records as soon as an INSERT or UPDATE happens?

Comment: @GiorgosAltanis It has to get the record set (s) whenever the department had changed in the history. Like for 001, the department has changed from English-Science and the date is Feb 4. Likewise, he has changed from Science - Math and the date is Apr 4. This applies for all IDs

Comment: @VladimirBaranov the version is 2012

Comment: So, now you have your answer, what is it about send and receive?

Comment: @GiorgosAltanis Send and receive are part of query notifications that would notify the application about the changes in data. I thought if something of that sort needs to be done for this usecase

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do it is to use `ROW_NUMBER` function with partitioning to detect when the value of the `Department` column changes.

**Sample data**

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (ID int, Department nvarchar(100), dt date);
INSERT INTO @T (ID, Department, dt) VALUES
(1, 'English', 'Feb 3 2017'),
(1, 'English', 'Feb 4 2017'),
(1, 'Science', 'Mar 1 2017'),
(1, 'Science', 'Apr 2 2017'),
(1, 'Maths  ', 'Apr 7 2017'),
(2, 'Maths  ', 'Feb 1 2017'),
(2, 'Maths  ', 'Apr 7 2017'),
(3, 'Maths  ', 'Apr 3 2017'),
(4, 'Science', 'Feb 1 2017'),
(4, 'Maths  ', 'Apr 7 2017');
```

**Query**

```
WITH
CTE
AS
(
    SELECT
        ID
        ,Department
        ,dt
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID, Department ORDER BY dt DESC) AS rnPart
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY dt DESC) AS rnID
    FROM @T
)
SELECT
    ID
    ,Department
    ,dt
FROM CTE
WHERE
    rnPart = 1
    AND rnID <> 1
ORDER BY
    ID
    ,dt
;
```

**Result**

```
+----+------------+------------+
| ID | Department |     dt     |
+----+------------+------------+
|  1 | English    | 2017-02-04 |
|  1 | Science    | 2017-04-02 |
|  4 | Science    | 2017-02-01 |
+----+------------+------------+
```

Comment: Renamed `dt` to `date` to match the column names Poppy has. Good job!

Comment: @GiorgosAltanis, it is just an example. I don't like to use reserved words for column names.

Comment: I understand ( and I agree). When I edited your answer you had not provided the sample code yet, so I wanted to make sure that OP understands that this solution works.

Comment: @VladimirBaranov If the student has changed from department A (in the past) to department A again, how would the partition work.

Comment: @Poppy, do you mean from A to B, then from B back to A, then to C? In this case my query would return only the last date of A. It would not return two rows with A. I think it would be better if you asked another question with more extensive sample data that covers all important cases. If I understood you correctly, the query would be quite different and more complicated.

Comment: @Vladimir Baranov, yeah. exactly.. the student 001 changes from dept a to dept b, dept c and then back to dept a. Can you please help me with this updated logic

Comment: @Poppy, ask a new question and include sample data and expected result that cover all cases.

Comment: @VladimirBaranov  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43316743/how-to-find-the-changes-in-records-in-sql-server

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by creating after insert/update trigger on the tables that you need to track. Using the logical tables Inserted/Deleted in sql server you can track the newly inserted and modified fields on a table.

Inserted (Logical table):It'll give you the details of the newly inserted records/updated values (column values).

Deleted(Logical Table): It'll give you the old value of a field before it got modified/deleted.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not that sure about it but you can get help with the concept of stored procedures. They are functions which are a part of database. You can set the display when you make the query