# How to find the changes in records in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table which holds student info.

```
+==========================================+
| ID      |  Department     | Date         |
+==========================================+
| 001     | English         | Feb 3 2017   |
| 001     | English         | Feb 4 2017   |
| 001     | Science         | Mar 1 2017   |
| 001     | Maths           | Mar 2 2017   |
| 001     | Maths           | Mar 21 2017  |
| 001     | Maths           | Apr 2 2017   |
| 001     | English         | Apr 7 2017   |
| 002     | Maths           | Feb 1 2017   |
| 002     | Maths           | Apr 7 2017   |
| 003     | Maths           | Apr 3 2017   |
| 003     | Maths           | Apr 7 2017   |
| 004     | Science         | Feb 1 2017   |
| 004     | Science         | Mar 1 2017   |
| 004     | Maths           | Apr 7 2017   |
| 004     | English         | Apr 9 2017   |
+==========================================+
```

In the above table I need to get the list of student records whenever the student's department preference is changed. There is also a chance that student can change back to the same department again. So for the above sample data, the list of records returned would be

**For student 001**

```
| 001     | English         | Feb 4 2017   |
| 001     | Science         | Mar 1 2017   |
| 001     | Maths           | Apr 2 2017   |
```

**002 and 003 Nothing**

**for 004**

```
| 004     | Science         | Mar 1 2017   |
| 004     | Maths           | Apr 7 2017   |
```

When I try to apply the logic mentioned in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43270488/how-to-track-changes-in-records-in-sql-server/43270684), partition on doesn't work as the student can come back to the same department again. Kindly help.

Comment: What you describe and what you present as a result is different and which makes confusion.

Comment: @RameshKharbuja I am trying to find the records where the user preference in department has changed. Please let me know what's causing confusion.

Comment: There is no row for english in your result for student 1 and 4 although there is change math to english for bothy student 1 and 4

Comment: Why for ID 004 record skipped in output where he changed his department from Maths to English on Apr 9th?

Comment: @RameshKharbuja . Considering user 1, 
his preference has changed from english - science  and the date is feb 4. similarly, from science-math its mar 1 and his preference continues to be math till apr 2 after which he changes to english. So the sample result shows 3 rows as given above.

Comment: @ShakeerMirza the user has changed from maths to english and thats why the April 7th record is shown in the sample result. I am checking the changes in history. excluding the current one. For user 004, the last update is by April 9 to english dept which is his current preference. so that is not included in result set

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `LEAD` window function - for SQL version 2012 and later...

```
DECLARE @SampleData AS TABLE 
(
   Id int,
   Department varchar(20),
   [Date] date
)

INSERT INTO @SampleData
VALUES (1,'English', 'Feb 3 2017'),(1,'English', 'Feb 4 2017'),(1,'Science', 'Mar 1 2017'),
(1,'Maths', 'Mar 2 2017'),(1,'Maths', 'Mar 3 2017'),(1,'English', 'Mar 7 2017'),
(2,'Maths', 'Feb 3 2017'),(2,'Maths', 'Feb 4 2017'),
(3,'Maths', 'Feb 3 2017'), (3,'Maths', 'Feb 4 2017'),
(4,'Science', 'Feb 1 2017'), (4,'Science', 'Feb 2 2017'), (4,'Maths', 'Feb 3 2017'),(4,'English', 'Feb 4 2017')

;WITH temps AS 
(
   SELECT sd.*, LEAD(sd.Department, 1) OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY sd.[Date])  AS NextDepartment
   FROM @SampleData sd    
)
SELECT t.id, t.Department,t.[Date] FROM temps t
WHERE t.Department != t.NextDepartment
```

Demo link: [Rextester](http://rextester.com/SVVA33279)

Reference link: [LEAD - MDSN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lead-transact-sql)

For older version you could use `OUTER APPLY`

```
SELECT sd.*
FROM @SampleData sd
OUTER APPLY 
(
   SELECT TOP 1 * FROM @SampleData sd2 WHERE sd.Id = sd2.Id AND sd.[Date] < sd2.[Date]
) nextDepartment
WHERE sd.Department != nextDepartment.Department
```

Comment: SQL Server 2012 and above only.